# ManyToMany в Джанго

Tags: django, django-orm

Перечитал документацию Джанго и никак не могу решить задачу.

Например есть две модели `Cart` и `Products`:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    cartnumber = models.CharField()
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products)
    total = DecimalField()

class Products(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    price = DecimalField()
```

Все связывается хорошо, в админке тоже все отлично, но задача в другом.
Как я понимаю, при `ManyToMany` создается промежуточная таблица с `id` таблиц `Cart` и `Products`. Но мне нужно чтоб в этой промежуточной таблице были еще поля, например объем заказываемого продукта, его сумма.
Не понимаю как организовать это дело. Может быть я неправильно себе представляю суть? Подскажите люди добрые, как мне организовать грамотно работу корзины с несколькими товарами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильным решением является изменение логики работы с корзиной и полный отказ от модели `Cart` и отношений many-to-many

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='basket')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+')
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    @property
    def cost(self):
        return self.product.price * self.count
```

Но можно сделать и с помощью [промежуточной модели](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    cartnumber = models.CharField()
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products, through='Purchase')
    total = DecimalField()

class Purchase(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    cost = DecimalField()
```

Comment: В первом варианте получается что каждому продукту из корзины будет своя запись в таблице Purchase? В моем случае нужно чтобы было несколько товаров ссылаемые на одну таблицу. Второй случай пробовал, возможно я что-то делаю не так, но как только добавляю through='Purchase' из админки пропадает поле.

Comment: В первом случае без проблем, пользователь покупает десять товаров, создаётся 10 экземпляров `Purchase`. Во втором придётся [использовать инлайны для отображения промежуточной таблицы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).